# RestAssured.get(url).statusCode causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, httpresponse, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured.get(url).statusCode() to see if a url is working and respond successfully(Code 200) or not. In case of some urls(like url1) it properly works but for some  urls(such as url2) it will cause the following error:

```
String url1="http://www.bbsys.com/playersdemo.exe"
String url2="http://www.ezhomeinspectionsoftware.com/filestorage/EZ-Setup.exe"
```

both of these urls result in downloading files. But the second one downloads a bigger file. So, probably that's why it cause out of memory exception. I need to know how can I handle cases like this. I need to get response from a large number of different urls. Do you recommend using another library or I'm using this library in a wrong way?

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at io.restassured.internal.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:31)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.GZIPEncoding$GZIPDecompressingEntity.getContent(GZIPEncoding.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:85)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:545)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.super$2$parseResponse(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.parseResponse(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2137)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2073)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1450)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to download the files or do you only want to check if the url is alive?

If not take, a look at the `head` method (https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/RestAssured.html#head-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-), to send a head request without triggering the download.

Otherwise your only option is to provide sufficient memory, as @Roberto suggested.